# Pandas .min() skipna option not working for mixed string and NaN Series

Tags: string, pandas, max, nan, min

I have a Pandas Series that basically is a mixture of strings and `np.nan`. My goal is to take the `min()` and `max()` excluding all the `NaN`. What would be the best way to do it?

For instance, using the Pandas built-in `.min()` doens't work:

```
(Pdb) x
0         NaN
1    20180101
2    20170101
Name: DATE, dtype: object

(Pdb) x.min()
*** TypeError: unorderable types: float() <= str()

(Pdb) x.min(skipna=True)
*** TypeError: unorderable types: float() <= str()
```

I'd like to return `20170101` in the above case. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the null values when you calculate: `s[s.notnull()].min()`

Comment: `s.dropna().min()` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dropna` or boolean indexing to remove NaN then use `min`:

```
s.dropna().min()
```

or as @ALollz points out in comments

```
s[s.notnull()].min()
```

Output:

```
'20170101'
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have dates. A third alternative would then be to use the fact that you have dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [np.nan, '20180101','20170101']
})

m = pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).min().date()
print(m)
```

Results:

```
2017-01-01
```